# How to remove page caching using java

Tags: java, http-caching

My web pages are cached even when i used session.invalidate method. How can i remove caching of pages using java coding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511144/how-to-instruct-web-browsers-not-to-cache-pages

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the appropriate headers in your pages so that they are not cached by the browser:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1);
```

and

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```