# css iframe not updated on client after update

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a webapplication (asp.net / html, css, etc).
I've updated my stylesheet and deployed it on my webserver.
Now some of my users / customers are still using the old css files.

I did this already

My telephone is ringing and I have to tell my customers to use F5 to reload the page. After that the stylesheet is updated.

My webapplication is using iframes. The problem maybe within the iframes?

Comment: I'd face a similar kind of issue, I just use to append a parameter with random generated value...I know this is a ugly trick but for me it worked..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox (and other browsers), [**F5** is simple refresh while **CTRL + F5** forces a cache refreh too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate) and force reload static resources, you should tell them to do `CTRL + F5` at the phone...

Your problem is cache-related, if you don't want the browsers to cache your `CSS`s you can instruct them with metatags and writing to the response setting the `Cache-Control` attribute ([take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511144/how-to-instruct-web-browsers-not-to-cache-pages))

Or you can configure it in your Web Server directly (in Apache it would be something like

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 1 second”
```

Or use some ugly trick like adding timestamp to the link to CSS: http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

BTW the cache will expires on its own somewhere in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You can adding "version" in yoh html code
Such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?version123" />
```

All users will using newest css file